# what is the C# compiler option for specifying the version of .net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, csc

I have look completely in this two msdn article [C# Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx)  and [C# Compiler Options Listed by Category](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s2x2bzy.aspx) for compiler option for specifying the target framework version which can be used in command line building. I got to know that we can specify the framework version in app.config with `supportedRuntime` element.

Can we use this element(`configuration`>`startup`>`supportedRuntime`) in web.config also(in case of asp.net application) ?

I have not needed to do it with only command line switch. I just asking this question only because of curious to know about it.

Comment: Isn't it determined by the version of the .net framework that you're running CSC from? e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe would compile for .net 4

Comment: You can either specify the full path for the references `/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll` or specify the folder for all references like `/lib:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't care about what version of the **framework**, only the version of the **runtime** and the **language**.

The `cl.exe` program just compiles and links whatever you throw at it, and it is up to you to add references to .NET 4.5-specific assemblies or not. You can choose to reference older versions of external references by specifically asking for a version using a fully qualified assembly name.

The setting in Visual Studio is just a filter that shows/hides assemblies when you are adding references.